# '*' Causing SSIS Errors

Tags: sql, ssis

When I'm using SSIS to transfer data from one table to another it gives me an error and I think it's because some fields have an *. Is there anyway I can remove this from all the fields? There is no way to tell which field or column it will appear in as it's some sort of an indication of a footnote.

Error:

> OLE DB Destination [40]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult:
>   0x80004005 Description: "Invalid character value for cast
>   specification".

Thanks for any assistance.

Cheers

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: [OLE DB Destination [40]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

Comment: The field normally contains a score like '9' but if they don't have a score available it shows up as 'Not Available' or 'Not Available*'. Also if the score is only a partial score it will show up as '9*'. Could the '*' be removed somehow in SQL?

Comment: so what is the source and  destination data type for that field?

Comment: I have the source set as VARCHAR 500 and then the Destination as int for some and Varchar for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ending up using Case statements for each field containing an '*'. So that each time it found an '*' it would replace the field with Null since the '*' identified the field as a not fully calculated field. Doing so then allowed my SSIS package to execute without error.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this of removing non numeric characters from score column in multiple ways using TSQL and SSIS

using the below code just replace the field score in below tsql with column that contains score in your query.

```
SELECT
     (SELECT CAST(CAST((
        SELECT SUBSTRING(score, Number, 1)
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(' ') AND
            SUBSTRING(score, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path(''))
    AS xml) AS varchar(MAX)))
```

Second solution using SSIS script transformation task you can use either VB or C# to using regex function to strip non numeric characters, below example uses VB, just change the Row.ColumName to field that contains the score in the data flow.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Overrides Sub Input()_ProcessInputRows(ByVal Row As Input()Buffer)

     If Row.ColumnName_IsNull = False Or Row.ColumnName = "" Then

           Dim pattern As String = String.Empty

           Dim r As Regex = Nothing

           pattern = "[^0-9]"

           r = New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled)

           Row.ColumnName = Regex.Replace(Row.ColumnName, pattern, "")

      End If

End Sub
```